# Adding new fields to checkout form java update

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajaxform

I'm trying to change out some fields on my check out form. I currently have one item with 3 options via a color dropbox: Black, Red, Blue that all works fine. My issue is some customers want to purchase more than one color, So they have to return to do so. This is basically a 1 item "purchase form" rather a shopping cart.

And in need "var shipping" and var itemTotalValue to also update proprely

This is the code I'm removing:

```
    <select id="item-options">
      <option value="2-Black" price="9.99">Black - 9.99 USD</option>
      <option value="2-Red" price="9.99">Red - 9.99 USD</option>
      <option value="2-Blue" price="9.99">Blue - 9.99 USD</option>
    </select>
    
    <select id="quantitySelect">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
```

And this is the code I need to add:

```
    <p>Black <input type="text" name="Black" size="2" value="0" id="quantitySelect0"></p>
    <p>Red <input type="text" name="Red" size="2" value="0" id="quantitySelect1"></p>
    <p>Blue <input type="text" name="Blue" size="2" value="0" id="quantitySelect2"></p>
```

I have issues getting it to work here is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Some type of item</title>
</head>

<body>
    
<div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1.25rem;">
          <p>Some type of item</p>
          
          <!-- I want to remove this -->  
           <select id="item-options">
              <option value="2-Black" price="9.99">Black - 9.99 USD</option>
              <option value="2-Red" price="9.99">Red - 9.99 USD</option>
              <option value="2-Blue" price="9.99">Blue - 9.99 USD</option>
            </select>
            
            <select id="quantitySelect">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
          <!-- End Remove -->
          
          <!-- I want to add this -->              
            <p>Black <input type="text" name="Black" size="2" value="0" id="quantitySelect0"></p>
            <p>Red <input type="text" name="Red" size="2" value="0" id="quantitySelect1"></p>
            <p>Blue <input type="text" name="Blue" size="2" value="0" id="quantitySelect2"></p>
          <!-- End Add -->
           
        </div>
        
        
        
      <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
    
    function initPayPalButton() {
        var shipping = 3.50;
        var quantity = parseInt(10);
        
        var itemOptions = document.querySelector("#smart-button-container #item-options");
        var quantitySelect = document.querySelector("#smart-button-container #quantitySelect");
    
    var orderDescription = 'Some type of item';
    
    if(orderDescription === '') {
      orderDescription = 'Item';
    }
    
    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        shape: 'pill',
        color: 'silver',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'buynow',
        
      },
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        var selectedItemDescription = itemOptions.options[itemOptions.selectedIndex].value;
        var selectedItemPrice = parseFloat(itemOptions.options[itemOptions.selectedIndex].getAttribute("price"));
        var tax = (0 === 0) ? 0 : (selectedItemPrice * (parseFloat(0)/100));
        
        if(quantitySelect.options.length > 0) {
          quantity = parseInt(quantitySelect.options[quantitySelect.selectedIndex].value);
        } else {
          quantity = 1;
        }

        tax *= quantity;
        tax = Math.round(tax * 100) / 100;
        var priceTotal = quantity * selectedItemPrice + parseFloat(shipping) + tax;
        
        priceTotal = Math.round(priceTotal * 100) / 100;
        var itemTotalValue = Math.round((selectedItemPrice * quantity) * 100) / 100;

        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            description: orderDescription,
            amount: {
              currency_code: 'USD',
              value: priceTotal,
              breakdown: {
                item_total: {
                  currency_code: 'USD',
                  value: itemTotalValue,
                },
                shipping: {
                  currency_code: 'USD',
                  value: shipping,
                },
                tax_total: {
                  currency_code: 'USD',
                  value: tax,
                }
              }
            },
            items: [{
              name: selectedItemDescription,
              unit_amount: {
                currency_code: 'USD',
                value: selectedItemPrice,
              },
              quantity: quantity
            }]
          }]
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
          alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        });
      },
      onError: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      },
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }
  initPayPalButton();
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what doesn't work ? are you getting any error ?

Comment: I'm trying to add fields to this from as described in post